# Algebra for a polytropic process, thermo

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Polytropic process equation

$p_1v_1^n=p_2v_2^n$

$pv=RT$ Where R is a constant, (Ideal gas law)

How do you obtain the expression:

$\frac{T_2}{T_1}=\left (\frac{p_2}{p_1}\right)^\frac{n-1}{n}$

I get $\frac{p_2}{p_1}=\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)^n=(\frac{T_1}{T_2})^n(\frac{p_2}{p_1})^n$

I dont know what to do from here or if it even correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{T_2}{T_1} = \dfrac{p_2}{p_1}\dfrac{\frac{RT_2}{p_2}}{\frac{RT_1}{p_1}} = \dfrac{p_2}{p_1}\dfrac{v_2}{v_1} = \dfrac{p_2}{p_1}\big(\dfrac{p_1}{p_2}\big)^{1/n} = \big(\dfrac{p_1}{p_2}\big)^{1/n - 1} = \big(\dfrac{p_1}{p_2}\big)^{(1 - n)/n} = \big(\dfrac{p_2}{p_1}\big)^{(n - 1)/n}$

Comment: How did you go from $\dfrac{p_2}{p_1}\big(\dfrac{p_1}{p_2}\big)^{1/n} = \big(\dfrac{p_1}{p_2}\big)^{1/n - 1}$  and $\frac{1}{n-1}=\frac{(1-n)}{n}$

Comment: $\frac{p_2}{p_1} = \big(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\big)^{-1}$ and the exponent in the answer is $(1/n) - 1$.